# Override default header and show custom button

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Here is my `index.html`

```
  <body ng-app="mobApp">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
```

Here is my page

```
<ion-view view-title="Update about">
<ion-header-bar align-title="left" class="bar-positive">
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button" ng-click="doSomething()">Left Button</button>
  </div>
  <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button">Right Button</button>
  </div>
</ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
        <div class="list">        
          <label class="item item-input">
            <textarea placeholder="Write about yourself"></textarea>
          </label>
        </div>  
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Here inside header no left or right button is showing its just showing default back button with title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `hide-back-button="true"` in `<ion-view>` tag to hide default back button. And add navigation buttons like this :

```
<ion-view view-title="Update about" hide-back-button="true">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button" ng-click="doSomething()">Left Button</button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button">Right Button</button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content>
        <div class="list">        
          <label class="item item-input">
            <textarea placeholder="Write about yourself"></textarea>
          </label>
        </div>  
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Just use `<ion-nav-buttons>` with others no change. It does work.